# how to display the content of an element using <xls:if

Tags: xml, xslt-2.0

hi i would like some help to come up with a function that would display the content of element  if (station>='BBC'....tried -xsl:if test=("@station ='BBC'")> with no aveil.

```
<chanels>
      <public>
       <programme>
         <station>BBC</station>
         <sports>soccer</sports>
         <news>local</news>
         <studio>london</studio>
         <drama>british Got talent</drama>
       </programme>
      <programme>
         <station>CNN</station>
         <sports>soccer</sports>
         <news>local</news>
         <studio>new York</studio>
         <drama>american circus</drama>
       </programme>
       <programme>
         <station>FOX8</station>
         <sports>soccer</sports>
         <news>local</news>
         <studio>Florida</studio>
         <drama>ET</drama>
       </programme>
    </public>
    </chanels>
```

Comment: Are you seeking cases where the value of the `station` child is 'BBC'? or where it is greater than or equal to 'BBC'?

Comment: hey,.was seeking the equal to value,.its done now,.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the '@' is only used for referencing attributes of nodes. You need to use something like this:

```
<xsl:if test="station='BBC'">
...
</xsl:if>
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Reinder pointed out in his answer, `@` is used to reference attributes, not elements. Use for example the following XSL stylesheet to produce an exact copy of your input with just those `<programme />` elements, whose `<station />` is equal to `'BBC'`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:transform version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" /></xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="programme">
        <xsl:if test="./station = 'BBC'">
            <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" /></xsl:copy>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

Comment: thank,.for an alternative solution,.